# Fill a matrix with an array

Tags: python, matrix

I have some code of which I obtain an array of different values within a double for loop. I assign it to a list `test`

and I want to set them one by one on this matrix of 8 x 8

I have tried:

```
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        matrixc[i][j] = testi[i]
```

I want to have a different value on each tuple. How can I advance through the list on each iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        matrixc[i][j] = testi[i*8 + j]
```

Alternatively:

```
for index, element in enumerate(testi):
    matrixc[index / 8][index % 8] = element
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're pulling from a linear array then you could access it using `array[i*8 + j]` instead of `array[i]`